# How to return objects from a list that matches certain criterias - Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, search

I'm Writing a search function where I'm searching through a list for matching Words or characters. It looks like

```
    def search(seq, db):
        return match(db, seq)
```

Where match is a recursive function which searches through the lists and returns a boolean value. 
How do I return a list with the matching objects instead of just True or False?

The match functions looks like this:

```
def match(seq, pattern):

    if not pattern:
        return not seq

    elif pattern[0] == '--':

        if match(seq, pattern[1:]):
            return True

        elif not seq:
            return False

        else:
            return match(seq[1:], pattern)

    elif not seq: 
        return False 

    elif pattern[0] == '&':
        return match(seq[1:], pattern[1:])

    elif seq[0] == pattern[0]:
        return match(seq[1:], pattern[1:])

    elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return match(seq[0], pattern)

    elif isinstance(pattern[0], list):
        return match(seq, pattern[0])

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `def match(db, seq):
    return [bool(i) for i in db if i in seq]`

Comment: What do you mean with def match? match is already a completed function which we only use to search through the lists. We need the search function to call match function and then pick out the elements that matches.

Comment: I mean is match function like mine since you are calling it?

Comment: I edited the posts and added the match function, it a finished function I've got so it should be like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your `match` function is doing.  I'm guessing you're wanting the `match` function to return a list instead of a boolean value.

You can start by changing your base cases.  Everywhere you see `return False` or `return True` instead say 'return []`or`return [seq[0]]`(assuming`seq[0]` is a sensible thing to be returned in your list of matches).

With your `return match(...)` recursive cases you could `return [seq[0]] + match(...)` or something similar to add the current match (when applicable) to the listed returned by the recursive call.

This method of prepending lists is not particularly efficient, but I doubt that your concern now.